# Delete all users meta that named: user_avatar

Tags: database, mysql, sql

I want a code like this:

```
UPDATE `jnkdadb7a_usermeta` SET `meta_key`='x1' WHERE (`meta_key` = 'x2');
```

I want a SQL command to search inside jnkdadb7a_usermeta table for meta_key (X) and delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
DELETE FROM jnkdadb7a_usermeta WHERE meta_key='X';
```

Comment: Glad i could help...